# One table to few classes, that using inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

I' ve got a few of classes (and tables) like `Source1`, `Source2` etc.
I create one table to store source Quant values. Table looks like

```
SourceQuant(ID int PRIMARY KEY, SourceKeyID int, TypeID int, Quant money)
```

I use EF inheritance strategy by TPH, and by TypeID it know's which type is stored. So i've got about 10 different classes.
And now I need to create table like Action History when quant from one Storage move to another.
I create table that looks like

```
ActionHistory(
  ID int Primary Key,
  SourceTypeID int, SourceKeyID int, 
  DestTypeID   int, DestKeyID   int,
  Quant money)
```

How can I do it in EF without creating 90 (10*9) classes like `Source1ToSorce2`, `Source1ToSource3`, `Source2ToSource4` etc?